# Serenity session variable usage

Tags: serenity-bdd

Hi team am new to serenity. Let's say am storing this data as follows

```
Serenity.setSessionVariable("User Name").to("userKey");
```

Now in a scenario if I call this key like this `Serenity.sessionVariableCalled("userKey")` from a different step definition in a different class will I get the value saved?.

Answer (score 1):

if it is a scenario different from which you call the session variable, it is not possible.
the scenarios are independent  -> SOLID

Answer (score 0):

It should return that object, but you may need to typecast it. 
Also Serenity.sessionVariableCalled("userKey") is calling 
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get("objectKey")

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from StackOverflow Help.